# Java AWT TextField Size Issue

Tags: java, size, awt, textfield, frame

Currently, I'm working on java Frame. I have an issue with making the size of the textfield bigger since I can't really see what I typed. I used command+a, then copied and pasted what I typed in another textarea, and it showed as I typed. However, I want to make my textfield bigger. Please let me know what I can do.

This is main class.

```
public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Frame f = new Frame("This is practice title bar!");
        f.addWindowListener(new ExitListener());
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1,20,20));

        Panel myPanel = new Panel();
        myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,20,20));
        Label lName = new Label("Name");
        lName.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
        myPanel.add(lName);
        Label lAge = new Label("Age");
        lAge.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
        myPanel.add(lAge);
        Label lWeight = new Label("Weight");
        lWeight.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
        myPanel.add(lWeight);
        TextField tfName = new TextField();
        myPanel.add(tfName);
        TextField tfAge = new TextField();
        myPanel.add(tfAge);
        kgPanel kp = new kgPanel();
        myPanel.add(kp);
        Label empty = new Label("");
        myPanel.add(empty);
        Button addBtn = new Button("Add");
        addBtn.addActionListener(new UserActionListener());
        myPanel.add(addBtn);
        Label empty2 = new Label("");
        myPanel.add(empty2);
        f.add(myPanel);

        TextArea ta = new TextArea();
        f.add(ta);

        f.pack();
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
```

This is kgPanel class.

```
import java.awt.*;

public class kgPanel extends Panel
{
    public TextField weightTf = null;
    public Label measurement = null;
    public kgPanel()
    {
        tfAndKg();
    }
    public kgPanel(LayoutManager layout)
    {
        super(layout);
        tfAndKg();
    }
    public void tfAndKg()
    {
        weightTf = new TextField();
        add(weightTf);
        measurement = new Label("kg");
        add(measurement);
    }
}
```

[image]
And the image is a result. Please let me know which part should I edit to make my textfield bigger.

Thank you

I tried to use

> weightTf.setSize()

and

> weightTf.setBounds()

but didn't work.

Please help me.

Comment: Use Swing. Swing components start with a "J". JLabel, JTextField etc. Then when you create the JtextField you use something like `new JTextField(10)` to create a text field to hold about 10 characters.

Comment: Thank you for your replying! I added 10 next to TextField and it worked. Looks better than before! And yes I'll work on Swing, too. Thank you!